# Insert a web page in mssql table

Tags: php, html, text

i want to insert a web page (text format) in a table

When i do my query, it gives me a mistake. But when i remove the webpage (in a string), it works.
The variable is the $comment one. 
The row for message is text (not varchar(255))

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO [".$project."_spec].[IsMessage] (project, message, note) VALUES('".$project."', '".$comment."', '".$note."')";
       mssql_query($query_insert) or die(mssql_get_last_message() . "[ " . $query_insert . " ]");
```

Is there a way to convert HTML in text?

Thanks

Comment: HTML is text. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Show us some code. What is the error?

Comment: Can you include the error messages and queries you're using? Your question is too vague as it is now.

Comment: What error does it give you and what query are you using?

Comment: Post table definition, error message, and php code you use... I doubt someone can give correct answer without knowing any details. I'd guess you are not escaping text.

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection, as well as making this harder than it needs to be. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Comment: Make sure you're using UTF-8 encoding on your database, use text/blob field and use a PARAMETERIZED QUERY, not a generic SQL statement to insert this type of data into your table.

Answer (score 0):

Your are building your SQL code dynamically by injecting variables with random contents into your query:

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES('".$project."', '".$comment."', '".$note."')";
                                           ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

This way, it won't take long until you build an invalid query inadvertently:

```
$project = "Foo";
$comment = "It isn't ready yet";
$note = "See John's notes";
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES('".$project."', '".$comment."', '".$note."')";
var_dump($query_insert);
// string(71) "INSERT INTO ... VALUES('Foo', 'It isn't ready yet', 'See John's notes')"
                                             ^      ^
                                Start string |      | End string... oops
```

I haven't used the legacy MSSQL extension so I don't know how you're supposed to fix this (apparently, you cannot!) but there's a [user comment that proposes a custom function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php#70078). You should drop the `stripslashes()` call but the rest looks correct (without actually having tested it).

If you happen to use Windows and it's not too late for a change, the newer [SQLSRV](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) provides a better feature set.